# How do I add HOST subnet?

Tags: python, fail2ban

Good afternoon.

Made a filter to catch IPv4 (working)

```
failregex = <HOST>
```

The [manual](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/MANUAL_0_8#Filters) states that the HOST is the alias of expression

```
(?:::f{4,6}:)?(?P<host>\S+)
```

**Question:** how to change the expression of the above, that it "eat" with the address of the subnet, for example, 1.1.1.1/24?

Thank you!

Comment: see [ipaddress](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html) module

Comment: I need to create a regular expression by the rules of python, I can not use modules.